# Printing matrix a & b

Tags: java, matrix, jgrasp

The program I wrote multiplies a 3 by 3 matrix. It asks the user to enter matrix a and matrix b and then it displays their product. I have done this however my only problem is that the output only prints the product I would like for it to print `matrix a * matrix b = product(a,b)`. I tried putting `System.out.println(a[i][j]+ " ");` above the `System.out.print(mul[i][j]+"");` 
but it messes up all the output and multiplication.

```
//this is my code:
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrices

{

 public static double[][] multiplyMatrix(double[][] a,double[][] b)

 {

      double c[][]=new double[3][3];

      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)

          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)

               for(int k=0;k<3;k++)

                    c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];

      return c;

  }


  public static void main(String args[])

 {

      //Create Scanner object to read input from user

      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

      double a[][]=new double[3][3];

      double b[][]=new double[3][3];

      double sum[][]=new double[3][3];

      double mul[][]=new double[3][3];



      //Read the elements of matrix b

      System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix a:");

      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)

          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)

               a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();


     System.out.print(a[i][j]+"")
      //Read the elements of Matrix b

      System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix b:");

      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)

          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)

               b[i][j]=sc.nextInt();


      //Call the method multiplyMatrix to multiply a and b

      mul=multiplyMatrix(a,b);


      System.out.println("Multiplication of two matrices:");




      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)

      {

          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)


          {

             System.out.print(mul[i][j]+"");                   

          }

          System.out.println();

          }   

      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Column wise output: You should be using three different loops in order to output three matrices: Matrix a * Matrix b = Product(a,b)

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
       System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");                   
   }
   System.out.println();
}   

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
       System.out.print(b[i][j]+" ");                   
   }
   System.out.println();
}  

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
       System.out.print(mul[i][j]+" ");                   
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Row wise output: Create a StringBuffer for each row. Add the 1st row of matrices a, b and mul to StringBuffer1 and print it out. Similarly for the other two rows.
Here's a link for the syntax of StringBuffer. http://www.java-examples.com/java-stringbuffer-examples

Comment: it prints it in a column how do i get it to print in a row

Comment: Please be more specific when you post the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
 System.out.println("Multiplication of two matrices:" + "\n");

 System.out.println("Matriz A");

 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a) + "\n");

 System.out.println("Matriz B");

 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(b)+ "\n");

 System.out.println("A x B");

 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mul)+ "\n");
```

Result:

```
Multiplication of two matrices:

Matriz A
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]

Matriz B
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]

A x B
[[30.0, 36.0, 42.0], [66.0, 81.0, 96.0], [102.0, 126.0, 150.0]]
```